# How to print the elements in odd positions in a list using an iterative function in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to make a recursive function in lisp which takes a list and makes another list with only the elements on odd position in the given list.

If I have `(1 2 3 4 5)` I have to output `(1 3 5)`

I have a code here:

```
(defun pozpar(lst) (do(
(l lst (cddr l)) 
(x '() (cons x (car l))))
((null l) x)))
```

This outputs:

```
(5 3 1)
```

I know `cons` adds the elements at the beginning and I tried with `append` or `list` but nothing worked.

Comment: There are a lot of Lisps. It looks like you're using Common Lisp here, so I suggest adding a tag for the *specific* Lisp that you're using.

Comment: This does not look like a *recursive* function. No recursion used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to [`reverse`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm) the result:

```
(defun pozpar (lst)
  (do ((l lst (cddr l))
       (x '() (cons (car l) x)))
      ((null l)
       (nreverse x))))

(pozpar '(1 2 3 4 5))
==> (1 3 5)
```

Notes

1. This *returns*, not *outputs* the value you want.
2. Prepending values and reverting the result is a common Lisp coding pattern.
3. Since [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) is *linear* in the length of its argument, using it in a loop produces *quadratic* code.
4. I formatted the code in the [standard Lisp way](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml). If you use this style, lispers will have an easier time reading your code, and, consequently, more willing to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a way easier solution:

```
(defun popzar (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) nil)
        (t (cons (car lst)
                 (popzar (cdr (cdr lst)))))))
```

It first checks if the list is empty and if not it creates a new list with the first element and the result of calling itself again with the rest of the list except for the second element.

Answer (score 1):

With using `loop` it's very easy to get the elements in the order you processed them. It is also the most effective and the only one guaranteed to work with all length arguments:

```
(defun pozpar1 (lst)
  (loop :for e :in lst :by #'cddr 
        :collect e)))
```

If you really want recursion I would have done it with an accumulator with a linear update reverse in the end:

```
(defun pozpar2 (lst)
  (labels ((helper (lst acc)
             (if (endp lst)
                 (nreverse acc)
                 (helper (cddr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))
    (helper lst '())))
```

However a classical not tail recursive version would look like this:

```
(defun pozpar3 (lst)
  (if (endp lst)
      '()
      (cons (car lst) (pozpar3 (cddr lst)))))
```